# Is there any resource for Bubble Chart using JasperReports?

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports

I am looking for `Bubble Chart` tutorials/example of *JasperReports*. I did get my expected resource yet, **sample program** and **`jrxml` template**. I already looking for online and `Jasper Ultimate Guide`. Why I ask this question is to keep the answer of this question here. Not other(eg: JavaFX Chart), I have to use *JasperReports*.

Any body help me provide simple program as below data(not theme).

Data

[image]

Chart

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got my example program for `JasperReport` `Bubble Chart` Example.

Data.java

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double z;

    public Data(String name, double x, double y, double z) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
    // getter, setter
}
```

BubbleChartTest.java

```
public class BubbleChartTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
        dataList.add(new Data("A", 1d, 3d, 0.3));
        dataList.add(new Data("A", 2d, 3d, 0.2));
        dataList.add(new Data("B", 5d, 6d, 0.4));
        dataList.add(new Data("B", 4d, 3d, 0.2));
        dataList.add(new Data("B", 2d, 5d, 0.1));
        dataList.add(new Data("C", 5d, 6d, 0.2));
        dataList.add(new Data("C", 2d, 3d, 0.3));
        dataList.add(new Data("C", 4d, 5d, 0.4));
        String templateFile = "resources/bubble.jrxml";
        JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(templateFile);
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
        Map parameter = new HashMap();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameter, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList));
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "D:/temp/bubble_chart.pdf");
    }
}
```

bubble.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="BubbleChartReport" columnCount="2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="270" columnSpacing="15" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="x" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="y" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="z" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="203">
            <bubbleChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report" theme="aegean">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="2" width="555" height="197"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <xyzDataset>
                    <xyzSeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <xValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{x}]]></xValueExpression>
                        <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{y}]]></yValueExpression>
                        <zValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{z}]]></zValueExpression>
                    </xyzSeries>
                </xyzDataset>
                <bubblePlot scaleType="RangeAxis">
                    <plot/>
                    <xAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </xAxisFormat>
                    <yAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </yAxisFormat>
                </bubblePlot>
            </bubbleChart>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
</jasperReport>
```

Output

[image]